# how can i compare two simpledateformat types in java with the following spec "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"

Tags: java, compare, simpledateformat

Hi i have two strings created from the simpleDateFormat type in java. They are as follows:

```
"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"
```

How can i compare two strings that have that format and know which is the latest?

Comment: why to create string and compare, where you can directly compare them in `Date`

Comment: they are simpleDateFormat not Date but if you know how to do it with Date please tell me how

Comment: @JoaoFilipeClementeMartins Why don't you use `Date#after` ?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#after%28java.util.Date%29

Comment: Note: In Java 8 there's a new class `java.time.format.DateFormatter` that I think is supposed to supplant all the previous `Calendar` and `Date` stuff.  However, I don't yet know how to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Convert the 2 Strings to `Date` objects using the [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). For more details on the conversion, you can refer [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion).
   Example: `Date date = new SimpleDateFormat(yourFormat).parse(dateString);`
2. Now compare the 2 `Date` objects using the [`Date#after()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#after(java.util.Date)) method.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to convert the strings back into a Date object like so:

```
        SimpleDateFormat defaultDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a", Locale.getDefault());
        Date myDate;
        try {
            myDate = defaultDateFormat.parse("insert your date/time string here");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            ...
        }
```

and then use

```
myDate.compareTo(myOtherDate)
```

to figure out which date is greater. the compareTo() method returns a -1,0, or 1 depending on which date is the latest.